# Openshift tomcat's logs: catalina.out and localhost.out contents

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, openshift

I have deployed my `WAR` application under `openshift`  `tomcat7` cartridge.

In my application I use `log4j`. My `log4j.properties` looks like:

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, A1, A2
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=myapp.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p (%t) [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p (%t) [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.A2.encoding=UTF-8
```

The problem is that in `$OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR` folder on my `openshift` app there are only two log files:

```
[myapp.rhcloud.com logs]\> ls
jbossews.log  postgresql.log
```

In `jbossews.log` I see only that logging lines which relates to `catalina.out` if run application under local `Tomcat 7`. More specifically, in `jbossews.log` I see general error info, like:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/54...1d/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/myapp.war
Mar 05, 2015 12:00:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 05, 2015 12:00:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 05, 2015 12:00:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/54...1d/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/myapp.war has
finished in 8,867 ms
```

But I can not see details of my errors, which are usually printed on `localhost.out` under local `Tomcat 7`.

So, how I can configure my gear or application to see full log? Thanks.

**UPD**: This is not about `log level`, because parts of log which I've missed are with `error` level. Furthemore, I can see such things if I run my app under local tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found here: https://forums.openshift.com/log4j-with-tomcat7-it-not-works

In brief: you have to proceed to `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` directory, upload here `log4j.jar` and configure `catalina.properties` to load `jars` from that directory:

`common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/.jar,/var/lib/openshift/51..36/app-root/data/libs/*.jar`

Comment: As much as it works for a non-scaled app, it would fail for scaled one. `data` folder is not replicated across. I'd rather put the `log4j.jar` into a subfolder of git repo, and modify `catalina.properties` accordingly, say: `common.loader=......${catalina.home}/../app-root/repo/myJars/*.jar`.

Comment: @ptrk thanks for you comment! I believe its very worth!

Answer (score 7):

We had been facing the same issue. In our case, we had a spring app which prints all the logs fine to `jbossews.log`, but if one of the beans threw an error during startup, the error stack trace would not print to `jbosews.log` or anywhere else. On a vanilla tomcat, these stack traces would print to `localhost.out` fine. We had tried the accepted solution, but it would not work for some reason.

However the below trick worked for us:

In the `.openshift/config/logging.properties` replace this:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

with this:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

For some reason by adding `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` as one of the handlers, the stack traces (and other messages) that go to `localhost.out` in vanilla tomcat now goes to `jbossews.log` in openshift.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm opening the log file from server direct

My problem was using command `tail` use `cat` to see the full file :

`cat app-root/logs/jbossews.log`